# Run shell script on demand in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode, xcode4.2

I have an iOS app project in Xcode 4.2. I also have a shell script which updates some files in the project. If I add it as a Build Phase for my app target, it obviously gets executed on each build. The problem is that I don't want such a behavior, I'd rather like it to be executed "on demand" (i.e., when I need it).

What is the correct way to achieve it? It feels like additional scheme or target may be involved, but I don't quite get it right.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my money, I'd put it into a separate project target.

M.

Comment: Well, this is what I ended up with, but it still feels a bit unsatisfying. Thanks for an answer, anyway.